# Stylus destructurable params mixin (margin-side: auto)

Tags: stylus

How to create a utility mixins with destrucutrable params? Like in standard css `margin: inherit auto` where the first argument is applied to top and bottom and second to right and left, *unless* additional args given.

```
margin-side(left, right)
  margin-left left
  margin-right right

.some-div
  margin-side auto
  // applied to both margin -left and -right
```

Using conditionals? Rest params? Default param values? Can't get it to work with any of those..

```
// thus far I've done it with
margin-side(left, right) ...
margin-sides(both) ...
// but it's error prone
```

Cheers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

I think it's what you try to do:

```
margin-side(vertical, horizontal = vertical)
  margin-top vertical
  margin-left horizontal
  margin-right horizontal
  margin-bottom vertical

.foo
  margin-side(10px)

.bar
  margin-side(5px, 7px)
```

[try it online](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=margin-side(vertical%2C%20horizontal%20%3D%20vertical)%0A%20%20margin-top%20vertical%0A%20%20margin-left%20horizontal%0A%20%20margin-right%20horizontal%0A%20%20margin-bottom%20vertical%0A%0A.foo%0A%20%20margin-side(10px)%0A%0A.bar%0A%20%20margin-side(5px%2C%207px))

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I've tried that tho must have messed something up because it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: don't forget that this is the default behaviors for `margin` css propertie so this mixin is probably useless https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Syntax

Comment: This specific one posted above yes (it's quite literally the same as "margin"). By side I meant horizontal only. So margin-side(left, right = left) { margin-left left; margin-right right; } Another good example is size(width, height=width) {...}